# Creating a unique index for a many to many relationship

Tags: postgresql

Say I have the following join table:

```
CREATE TABLE channel_users (
    channel_id uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES channels(id),
    user_id uuid NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

How would I go about creating a unique index that would stop me from inserting a row for the same users twice, on different channels?

For example:

```
channel_id | user_id
-----------|--------
         1 |       1
         1 |       2
         2 |       1 <-- this shouldn't exist
         2 |       2 <-- this shouldn't exist
```

I'm trying to implement a `find_or_create` function where the insert will fail if there is an existing channel between two users, and then a query would be run to get the channel where the joins exist.

I could do a find first and query on this join, but I'd like to perform this operation atomically so that two channels cannot be created for the same users.

---

I also think I'm approaching this wrong. I defaulted to `channel_id` | `user_id`, but I'm wondering if I should do something like `channel_id` | `user_ids`. Or perhaps some other similar approach.

Comment: It doesn't matter for uniqueness which order the columns of your index are in, if that's the only thing you're asking? Choose either. You might even want to have *both* indices depending on what lookups you need for the queries you run against the table.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a straightforward unique constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE channel_users ADD UNIQUE (user_id);
```